# Cannot resolve symbol movies

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a model called `Movie`. I am going to create a list of Movies and pass it to the view.
Here is the controller code:

```
[Route("movies")]
public ActionResult AllMovies()
{
    var movies = new List<Movie>
    {
        new Movie {Name = "Sherek"},
        new Movie {Name = "Halk"},
        new Movie {Name = "detector Gadget "}
    };
    return View(movies);
}
```

and here is the view code:

```
@using vidly.Models
@model List<Movie>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "AllMovies";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>AllMovies</h2>
<ul>
    @foreach (var movie in Model.movies)
    {
        <li>movie </li>
    }


</ul>
```

The problem is it does not recognize `movies` in the list. In line `Model.movies`, I face with the error:

> Movie does not contain a definition for movies and no extension method movies accepting a first argument of type Movie
>   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

Comment: Your model is `List<Movie>` and `List` does not contain a property named `movies`. Its `@foreach (var movie in Model) { <li>@movie.Name</li> }`

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your `foreach` statement to this

```
@foreach (var movie in Model)
{
    <li>
        movie.Name
    </li>
}
```

Comment: The type or namespace name 'List<vidly.Models>' could not be found

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your model from `List<Movie>` to `IEnumerable<Movie>`.

Answer (score 0):

Copy this code to your view , I think it should work

```C#
@model List<Vidly.Models.Movie>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "All Movies";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>AllMovies</h2>
<ul>
    @foreach (var movie in Model)
    {
        <li>@movie.Name</li>
    }
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Stephen Muecke.

I have `@model List<Movie>`, which somehow means `Model = List<Movie>`.
Therefore to achieve each movie in the list I have to do

```
foreach(var movie in Model)
```